# How to pass object to the layout view without action in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I would like to create in layout dynamic menu, which will be manage from administrative panel. 
What i know is the object can be pass to view by the action from controller.

What i want is pass object to layout ( twig engine ) without using controller and that will work independently form controller and action.

How can i do that?

Comment: After u registered the twig engine U could build up your object that is required and then use `$twig->addGlobal('my_object', $object);`. This way your object is accessible everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a global variable / object in Twig, you have to implement `Twig_Extension` and add a new global (which will be accessible to all your templates).

A simple example would be:

1) Register a service in `<bundle>/Resources/config/services.yml`

```
services:
  acme.twig.acme_extension:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\AcmeExtension
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

2) Then create the extension:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Twig

class AcmeExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
  public function getGlobals() {
    return [
      'menu' => new Menu(),
    ];
  }
}
```

3) Then in your template:

```
{{ menu.render }} // Whatever
```

Of course, you can pass arguments to the Twig extension if needed.

Anyway, if you're trying to build a menu, maybe you should have a look at KnpMenuBundle, which helps a lot (https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle)

Hope it helps!

Comment: thx for response , DarkBee said what i should do, i found solve but very thanks for your solution. I'm new in php and i don't know everythig :), one more thanks !